# Confusion between data matrix and dataset

Tags: mathematical-statistics, dataset

I am confused between the data matrix and dataset. I have a table like the following:

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|} 
 & \text{Column A} & \text{Column B}& \text{Column C}& \text{...}& \text{Column N} \\ \hline
\text{Row 1} & x_{11} & x_{12} & x_{13} & ... & x_{1n}\\ \hline
\text{Row 2} & x_{21} & x_{22} & x_{23} & ... & x_{2n}\\ \hline
\text{...} & ... & ... & ... & ... & ...\\ \hline
\text{Row M} & x_{m1} & x_{m2} & x_{m3} & ... & x_{mn}\\ \hline
\end{array}$$

Where, suppose, columns refer to timestamps and rows refer to attributes. I am using the table to describe structure of data.

Can we use the terms 'data matrix' and 'dataset' interchangeably in describing the above table? The definitions used in
[data matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Data_matrix_(multivariate_statistics)&redirect=no),  [data matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_matrix) and [dataset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_set) do not give a proper idea about the terms' frame of reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Matrix is a structure of data, for example in programming you are using matrices or arrays to hold the data (store the data). Another structure could be a binary tree. Data matrix refers to something like a placeholder.

The dataset from the other hand describes the whole amount of data. For example, a dataset is more like a group with images of animals;you have dogs, cats, birds etc.  One image from this dataset that represents pixels' intensity or color value, of a cat, it can be a data matrix. Dataset is a more general term, that describes a huge group. See Venn diagrams.

Another example is the whole set of real numbers (R) this is a dataset which contains all the real numbers. A data matrix could be a matrix contains real numbers that represents (x, y) points showing the location of an object inside a Cartesian axis systems like the four vertices of a square.

Hope that it will help you!

Comment: Thanks @TassosK.